# jQuery show more

Tags: jquery

hoping someone can help me.

I'm trying to have a "show more" link expand a hidden div and have the "show more" to disappear, but I need the list item its in to disappear as well. This needs to apply to multiple lists on the same page, and I need to be able to customize the "show more" text on a item by item basis.

Something that looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li><a class="toggle">Show More...</a></li>
<div class="toggle-wrap">
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

When you click the "Show More" it looks something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li style="display: none;"><a class="toggle">Show More...</a></li>
<div class="toggle-wrap">
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start by fixing the html: it is not valid to have a div as a direct descendant of a ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is invalid, since your `toggle-wrap` DIV is a direct child of your UL. To correct this, you can maybe give a class to all LI's that you want shown only when someone clicks 'Show More'. i.e. something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li><a class="toggle">Show More...</a></li>
    <li class="extra">Item</li> <!-- li's with class extra wont show up by default -->
    <li class="extra">Item</li>
    <li class="extra">Item</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

Once your HTML is in the above structure, the following should work for toggling:

```
$('li a.toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').hide();
    $(this).parent('li').siblings('extra').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your HTML is **invalid**. Instead of using a `<div>` element, use an **additional list**.
2. Use jQuery `bind('click')`, to toggle the child list.

View [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFJqg/)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment above, your html is invalid because you are not meant to have anything but li elements as direct descendants of a ul.

If the idea here is to hide the end of long lists until the user clicks "Show more..." then you can do something like this for your html (basically the same as you had minus the div):

```
<ul>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li><a class="toggle">Show More...</a></li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

And then in your document ready handler:

```
$('li a.toggle').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll().hide();
}).click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide()
           .nextAll().show();
});
```

This starts by finding all links with class "toggle" that are in an li and hiding all the following associated li elements.

The click handler gets the parent li of the clicked link and hides it, then gets the following sibling lis and shows them.

This will automatically work for multiple lists on the same page as shown in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v2pNS/